# Horizontal and Vertical Center within 100% CSS3's Viewport Height

Tags: html, css

I'm using the CSS3's Viewport Height to make a fullscreen section (height: 100vh). Unfortunately, I'm having trouble horizontally and vertically centering elements within a section. I'm attempting to have an image and bit of text within the first section appear in the center of the screen as a group. Thanks for the help!

http://jsfiddle.net/stybfgju/

HTML:

```
<section class="red-bg">
    <div class="middle">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/300/abstract/" alt="" />
        <h1>Some text here.</h1>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="blue-bg">
    <p>Another section here.</p>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.middle {
    /* needs to be vertically and horizontally aligned */
}

.red-bg {
    background-color: #f00;
}

.blue-bg {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try flexbox

```css
body {
    color: #fff;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display : flex;
}

.middle {
    /* needs to be vertically and horizontally aligned */
  margin : auto;
}

.red-bg {
    background-color: #f00;
}

.blue-bg {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<section class="red-bg">
    <div class="middle">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/300/abstract/" alt="" />
        <h1>Some text here.</h1>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="blue-bg">
    <p>Another section here.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/stybfgju/1/

```
.middle {
    /* vertical centering */
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

    /* horizontal centering */
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

- If you change `display` to `block` then you'll need to explicitly set `width`
- Add `text-align: center` if needed.